# Declare List as static on MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on load more data functionality as per my requirement I am displaying 12 records for the first time and it works fine for me but whenever I am trying to show the rest data the earlier data is getting lost and the current data is displaying.

For this purpose, I am using a list which is coming from code behind but my problem is I'd declared the List on the view which is initialized each and every time then every time it becomes null on at the time of data binding that is the reason earlier data is getting lost.

For this purpose, I can not use AJAX

Here is my View

```
@model List<ChangiRecommends.BAL.ViewModel.Product.ProductViewModel>
@using ChangiRecommends.BAL.ViewModel.Product;
@using ChangiRecommends.Utilities;
@{
    if(ViewBag.productCount > 12)
    {

    }
    List<ProductViewModel> productList = new List<ProductViewModel>();
    if(productList.Count == 0)
    {
        productList = Model;
    }
    else
    {
        productList.AddRange(Model);
    }
    ViewBag.Title = "destination";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var key = ViewBag.Key;
    var searchingKey = ViewBag.searchingkey;
    var skip = ViewBag.skip;
}

  <div class="destination_pics">
            <div class="row">
                @if (productList.Count>0)
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    foreach (var item in productList)
                    {
                        if (count == 0)
                        {
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="highlights">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("tourdetail", "customer",new {key = QueryStringManager.Encrypt(item.ID)})">
                                        <div class="highlithsTxt"> <p><strong>$@item.OnlinePrice</strong></p> <p>@item.ProductDisplayName</p> </div>
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="@item.ProductImage">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        else if (count > 0 && count <= 2)
                        {
                            if (count == 1)
                            {
                                @:<div class="col-sm-4">
                                }
                            <div class="highlights">
                                <a href="@Url.Action("tourdetail", "customer",new {key = QueryStringManager.Encrypt(item.ID)})">
                                    <div class="highlithsTxt"> <p><strong>$@item.OnlinePrice</strong></p> <p>@item.ProductDisplayName</p> </div>
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="@item.ProductImage">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            if (count == 2)
                            { 
                              @:</div>
                              <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            }
                        }
                        else if (count > 2 && count <= 5)
                        {
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="highlights">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("tourdetail", "customer",new {key = QueryStringManager.Encrypt(item.ID)})">
                                        <div class="highlithsTxt"> <p><strong>$@item.OnlinePrice</strong></p> <p>@item.ProductDisplayName</p> </div>
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="@item.ProductImage">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        else if (count > 5 && count <= 8)
                        {
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="card activityBox activeBox">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("tourdetail","customer",new {key = QueryStringManager.Encrypt(item.ID)})">
                                        <div class="dealTags">
                                            <div class="tag-spcial">Special Offer</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <img class="card-img-top" src="@item.ProductImage" alt="Card image cap">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <h5 class="card-title">@item.ProductDisplayName</h5>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-4 dealPrice">
                                                    <label>From</label>
                                                    $@item.OnlinePrice  <span>$30.00</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-5 dealLocation"><label>Location</label>@item.DestinationName</div>
                                                <div class="col-md-3 favIt"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        else if (count > 8 && count < 12)
                        {
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="card activityBox">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("tourdetail","customer",new {key = QueryStringManager.Encrypt(item.ID)})">
                                        <div class="dealTags">
                                            <div class="tag-spcial">Special Offer</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <img class="card-img-top" src="@item.ProductImage" alt="Card image cap">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <h5 class="card-title">@item.ProductDisplayName</h5>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-4 dealPrice">
                                                    <label>From</label>
                                                    $@item.OnlinePrice  <span>$30.00</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-5 dealLocation"><label>Location</label>@item.DestinationName</div>
                                                <div class="col-md-3 favIt"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (ViewBag.productCount > 12)
                    {
                        skip += 12;
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="loadMore"><a href="@Url.Action("destination","Home", new {key = key,searchingKey = searchingKey, skip = skip})"> Load More Results</a></div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this view, I'd declared a list on the top as it is initialized at every and I want to declare it as static so that the earlier data should not be lost.

Here is my controller.

```
public ActionResult destination(string key, string searchingkey, FilterDataViewModel model, int skip = 0)
    {
        TempData["HeaderColor"] = true;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                int destinationId = QueryStringManager.Decrypt(key);
                var destinationInfo = _masterRepo.GetMasterDataByID(destinationId);
                var productList = _websiteRepo.GetAllProductListByDestinationId(destinationId).OrderByDescending(x => x.DestinationWeightPriority).ToList();
                if (model.DestinationCityID > 0)
                {
                    productList = (from prod in productList where prod.DestinationCity == model.DestinationCityID select prod).ToList();
                }
                ViewBag.productCount = productList.Count();
                var a = productList.Skip(skip).Take(12).ToList();
                ViewBag.ProductList = productList.Skip(skip).Take(12).ToList();
                var allAdbyDestination = _websiteRepo.GetAllAdvertisementList(destinationId);
                ViewBag.allDestinationAd = allAdbyDestination;
                ViewBag.DestinationName = destinationInfo.MasterData;
                ViewBag.DestinationImages = destinationInfo.ImagePath;

                var categoryID = MasterConstant.GetCategoryID(CatergoryConstant.City);
                var allDestinationCity = _masterRepo.GetMasterDataByCategoryIDandXrefID(categoryID, destinationId);
                ViewBag.DestinationCityList = new SelectList(allDestinationCity, "ItemID", "MasterData");
                ViewBag.Key = key;
                ViewBag.searchingkey = searchingkey;
                ViewBag.skip = skip;
                return View(a);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Without javascript and ajax, the solution is not to skip at all, but to increase how many items you take.

Comment: Having a 'load more' not using ajax seems a bit pointless. But you would need to pass a value to the method that indicates how many records you want to display, and then use a `.Take()` in your query (no `.Skip()`) and increment the value for the next call

Comment: The `else` statement in `if(productList.Count == 0)` will never be true since you are creating a new list every time.

Comment: @X3Vikas, you have to pass `productList` to controller also, like you pass `skip` or `searchingkey` instead of creating new instance in view. so that your earlier data should be persist when you load new data